# Add Child Section to Web.config.release

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

In Web.config I have the system.webServer section:

```
<system.webServer>    
  <!-- Config Child Sections -->
</system.webServer>
```

In Web.config.release I need to add a new child section to system.webServer so I used:

```
<system.webServer>    
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Enforce WWW" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://(?!www)(.*)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>    
</system.webServer>
```

When I build it in release the rewrite section is not added.

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

You need to add xdt:Transfor="Replace" to your  tag:

```
<system.webServer xdt:Transform="Replace">
```

Without this the transformer don't know what to do with the tag. For more info please see: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

---

*******EDIT*****************
Then you could try:

```
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
```

Comment: But that will replace all system.webServer ... I would like to keep the webServer section I have in Web.config and add the child section rewrite which is not in the original system.webServer ...